# If cell in range doesn't equal blank then apply string to cell in another range

Tags: excel, vba

I have two ranges. ("A2:A81,H2:H81") and ("E2:E81,L2:L81")

("A2:A81,H2:H81") = search range and
("E2:E81,L2:L81") = string range

I have range (A2:A81,H2:H81) where I'm looking to see if a cell in the range is not blank. If one of those cells in this range is not blank and a cell in the "string range" is blank I want to put the string "No Punch" in the cell for that range.

Ex: If cell A10 is not blank and E10 is blank put the string "No Punch" when running the macro.

This is broken. I can use just the for each statement (without the if) but it fills all cells in the range that are blank and doesn't check the other range.

```
Sub FinishSheet()

    If (Worksheets("GerriSheet").Range("A2:A81,H2:H81").Value = "") Then

    For Each cell In Range("E2:E81,L2:L81")
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Value = "No Punch"
        End If
    Next cell

    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to loop the criteria range and use Offset()

```
Sub FinishSheet()
    For Each cell In Worksheets("GerriSheet").Range("A2:A81,H2:H81")
        If cell.Value = "" And cell.Offset(, 4).Value <> "" Then
            cell.Offset(, 4).Value = "No Punch"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Great use of `Offset()`. I wouldn't have done this. Guess that's what separates the newbies from the oldbies (?)

Comment: This is only changing the cells that are equal to "" in the first range. I basically need this 'If cell.Value <> "" Then' but only allow it to change the cells in the second range that are blank. if that makes since. :)

Comment: @James30263 yup, missed it and was editing the code.  See edit.

Comment: This one is doing the same thing because of the equal sign. Changing the = to <> did it! Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: The one that worked for me was the following. 'If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Offset(, 4).Value = "" Then'